# How to open Wildfly 8.2 JMX port for monitoring?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8, zabbix, centos7

I am using Wildfly 8.2 on CentOs. Can anyone help me to open remote JMX on Wildfly 8.2?

I am only using `standalone-full.xml` and the port 10990 is already accessible for webconsole like: `192.168.1.10:10990/console/`

Now, I am trying to monitor wildfly from jconsole and zabbix with my laptop, but it is not working.

Any help on this is appreciated...

Answer (score 9):

You should use `jconsole.sh` from `$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh`
and url

```
service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://192.168.1.10:10990
```

also allow external connection:

```
-Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.1.10
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the JMX service on wildly is accessible on port 9990. From your mail, it seems that it's running at 10990 for you.

To access WildFly over JMX **remotely** through `jconsole` following are the steps you need to follow:

1. On the WildFly server, create a management user using `add-user.sh`.
2. Get the `jboss-client.jar` from the WildFly server to your local laptop (from where you are planning to launch `jconsole`).
3. Invoke the following from your local laptop to start `jconsole`:

For Java 8:

> $JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole
> -J-Djava.class.path=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:<Location_On_Your_Laptop>/jboss-client.jar
> &

For Java 9+:

> $JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole -J--add-modules=jdk.unsupported -J-Djava.class.path=:/<Location_On_Your_Laptop>/jboss-client.jar &

4. On the `jconsole` pop-up window which comes up on your laptop, select "Remote Process". Provide the following URL:

```
service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://WildFly_Host:JMX_Port
```

For example, it could be: `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://1.2.3.4:9990`

5. Provide the username and password created in step #1.
6. Connect.